# What barebone set up for developing web apps in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I know its base on what you need, but in bare minimum what would be the best start up frameworks, task runners, plugins etc to develop real world web application? Im a noob but I think Il set it up as using:

Npm, angularjs ,jquery, expressjs, grunt, bower, bootstrap?

Then you just check which plugin you need for particular job?
Because alot of tutorials are pretty focus on just the angular side of things but never a real world development environment that could help with the job.

And follow up question is it advisable to have a dst and src folder and when youre done put everything in dst? What would be your take on this matter? Thank you

Comment: Off-topic for a couple of reasons. First, it asks for a recommendation, which is clearly mentioned as off-topic in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and second, it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: *Stackoverflow is not a place to ask for opinion related questions. It is a place to present the blockers in your code so that the community can help solve the issue. Please read the guidelines on 'how to ask a question' before asking.*

Comment: No problem. Ive already google this question and got no where. This is the closest thing i could think of to ask from experts about the best and efficient way for developing. And i appreciate any answer. I will however read the guidelines for asking thank you for pointing me to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And for your question, I would suggest [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). It creates all the boilerplate to start coding in Angular, including task manager with all most all the tasks you need, CSS and boiler plates, etc.. It even has a command-line interface which would help you create components, classes, services, etc of your app from the terminal.

Comment: If you're going to quote the guidelines against asking opinion based questions, then a) do so in a comment to the question itself, and b) don't then answer the question in defiance of those guidelines. Oh, and c) we don't accept (or answer) questions with product recommendations here, which are also off-topic. Perhaps a refresher on the guidelines in the [help] would be beneficial to you as well?